# Create CMAttitude rotation matrix from roll, pitch and yaw values

Tags: iphone, matrix, rotation, core-motion, pitch

I'm trying to get an (Apple style, CMAttitude) rotation matrix out of roll, pitch and yaw values. Does someone know how that conversion works?

Example:

roll: 1.01315,
pitch: 1.54177 and
yaw: -0.361097

should result in this rotation matrix:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve that with a CATransform3D.

You would use these two calls:

```
CATransform3D CATransform3DMakeRotation (CGFloat angle, CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat z);
CATransform3D CATransform3DRotate (CATransform3D t, CGFloat angle, CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat z)
```

You need to figure out how roll, pitch, and yaw correspond with your coordinate system (usually x, y, z, but could be z, x, y)

then just do a combo like this:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(anglex, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angley, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, anglez, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

your transform will now hold the matrix you are looking for.